# Check if SMTP is running or failed to send email

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I am using SMTP server to send emails.
I would like to get an error message when the SMTP server is down or when the email was not delivered.
With DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure I get an email that the email has not been delivered.
I would like to get an error. Is this possible?
How I can check if SMTP is running?

Here is the code I use:

```
Dim serverName As String = ""
Dim mailSenderInstance As SmtpClient = Nothing
Dim AnEmailMessage As New MailMessage
Dim sendersEmail As String = ""
Try
    serverName = GetServerName("EMAIL_SERVER")
    mailSenderInstance = New SmtpClient(serverName, 25)
    sendersEmail = GetSendersEmail(msUserName)
    AnEmailMessage.From = New MailAddress(sendersEmail)

   'MAIL DETAILS
    AnEmailMessage.Subject = "New Email"
    AnEmailMessage.Body = "The Message"
    AnEmailMessage.To.Add(anEmailAddress)

    ' Delivery notifications
    AnEmailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
    mailSenderInstance.UseDefaultCredentials = True 'False
    mailSenderInstance.Send(AnEmailMessage)

Catch ex As System.Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
Finally
    AnEmailMessage.Dispose()
    mailSenderInstance.Dispose() 
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

add another try catch block around your SMTP declaration

```
try
   mailSenderInstance = New SmtpClient(serverName, 25)
catch ex as exception
    msgbox( "Error creating SMTP connection: " & ex.message)
end try
```

regards

Comment: How this will help? When the server is not running it doesn't give me an error

Answer (score 0):

ok, you want to know the SMTP status. SMTP runs as a Service. I've written a function for you to know status of ANY service in the system. Add reference to "System.ServiceProcess" to your project.

```
''response: -1 = service missing, 0 = stopped or stopping, 1 = running

imports System.ServiceProcess ''add this at top 

Private Function GetServiceStatus(ByVal svcName As String) As Integer  
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Dim sc As New ServiceController(svcName)
    Try
        If sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
            retVal = 0
        Else
            retVal = 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        retVal = -1
    End Try
    Return retVal
End Function
```

use it like this:

```
'' use taskManager to figure correct service name
dim svStatus as integer = GetServiceStatus("SMTP") 
if svStatus <> 1 then 
  msgbox("Service not running or absent")
else
  ''write your send mail code here
end if
```

hope this will help you

Comment: A small problem. I cannot find any service related to SMTP? I am using windows 2007.

Comment: which web server are you using??

Comment: Exchange Server is running in another machine and in my computer I got outlook